# How To make if else in PHP from a response of JSON?

Tags: php, json

i have a json request if my pc has proxt set it shows yes if not then it shows No

Now i want to pubish two statement

if status is yes

i want to show you are protected (green)

if status No

then i want to show You are not Protected (red)

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://api.ip2proxy.com/?ip=$user_ip);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

?>
    <li>Your Status: 
        <span style="color:red"><?php echo $json['isProxy']; ?></span>
        
     <!--<span style="color:green"><?php echo $json['isProxy']; ?></span> -->
```

i am geeting result fine on display but i want to show custom text on display with custom style Not yes or not

Comment: Something like [this](https://3v4l.org/J4rCu) might help.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using if condtion

`<span style="color:red"><?php echo $json['isProxy'] == 'yes' ? something : otherthing; ?></span>`

Comment: HI Thak you your reply was very helpful but we are getting otherthing in both cases if proxy is  yes or No

in simple something is not working in both condition, it shows only otherthing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works now with simple if else condition